# How do I correctly redirect to a loading activity and then return to the current activity?

Tags: android

I have a load activity which sets up my statics/singletons and does some async tasks.

Since Android can kill an app and then reload it without it's statics, I'd like to add a simple check if any of the values I'm grabbing are null, and redirect to the load activity if that occurs (and then return when complete).  In this way, the user can return to what screen they were on when they left the app, but I can make sure I don't have any strange crashes.

What's the proper way to accomplish that activity redirect and then return?  Do I use the back stack for that or is there a more correct technique?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Fragment activity more than a Full activity, take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, then you can implement the logic on view create inside the fragment manager.

Comment: Are you sure?  A loading screen for the whole app hardly seems like the place for a fragment, but perhaps I'm mistaken?

Comment: From this figure (http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png) inside URL I shared, you can see when a fragment is active, hence the fragment itself is automatically inserted back stack. You can then determine if you want to ".replace" the fragment from FragmentManager and commit, or just keep the fragment running.